# what is the difference between mysql_close() and unset()?

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning php and Mysql database. All are sound good. But the following code make me confused :

```
if(isset($connection)){
           mysql_close($connection);
           unset($connection);
}
```

As far I know mysql_close() function is responsible to close a connection. So why additional unset() function has been used here? please explain it. thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but **why** are you using the `mysql_*` extensions if you're learning *now*, as that entire "package" is deprecated?

Comment: Expect to find a lot of bad code used in tutorials. The bad thing is that the internet never forgets, and this is true for old coding examples filled with now known bad habits or not using any great new features that make things a lot easier now. At least check which PHP version the tutorial or code example is for. Anything that is for 5.3 or older should be considered questionable. It might still be ok, but you should check whether this is actually still the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **[mysql_close($connection)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php)** closes the non-persistent connection to the MySQL server that's associated with $connection. If $connection isn't specified, the last opened link is used.

  -this function is deprecated , so please use PDO or mysqli.
- **[unset($connection)](http://php.about.com/od/phpfunctions/g/unset_php.htm)** clears the pointer to the result on php's side, but does not do anything to the result it points to.

Comment: Wouldn't GC kick in if there was no other references to `$connection`? Surely GC won't happen right away, though.

Comment: @h2ooooooo it would, but that still counts as "nothing" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The additional `unset()` would allow the garbage collection to clear up the memory that the closed `$connection` variable is taking up, also (most likely) your application codes do more `if (isset(...))` conditionals on that variable too.

Answer (score 0):

`unset($connection)` will just make the var `$connection` equal to `NULL`. If you didn't do the `unset`, then the var `$connection` would still point to a MySQL link identifier, which would be invalid after the `mysql_close()`. It's a little pedantic; whether you `unset` or not, the `$connection` var will not be usable after the `mysql_close()`.